# changing visibility of text android

Tags: android

Hi i have two textViews that i initially set its visibility to gone then animate in and become visible. now i want to make the invisible again but for some reason they're still showing on screen does anyone no why?

in my onCreate() i make the view gone

```
register = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        forgotpassword = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgotpw);
        forgotpassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then later on i make it visible

```
public void run() 
            {
               animations();
               loginForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               register.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               forgotpassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

and then when a user presses a button i want the text views to become invisible so that they retain their layout but they stay visible on screen

```
signInBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
        signInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                signInProcess();
            }
        });


 public void signInProcess() { 

     register.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     forgotpassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     setuploader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the `signInProcess()` function gets called?

Comment: yes i have edited my question to show you

Comment: is your animation function animating the signInButton?

Comment: yes its in a relative layout called login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android when you animate something, It's just drawn somewhere else. The actual element is not moved. So when you animate `signInBtn` it's drawn somewhere else, but the actual button is not moved from the original position. So when you click the button the click handler is not called.

To avoid this set `fillAfter = True` in your animation so the button will actually get moved at the end of your animation.

Also, after animating a view in Android make sure you call `View.clearAnimation()` before trying to change its visibility.